# can i configure 'git bash' to save my login info?

Tags: git, bash, authentication

When I make some git bash commands , like git pull , i have to enter my user and password.
is there a way to configure this so that i don't always have to enter user and password?

Thanks,  Peter

Answer (score 1):

You can store your username and you password with the following commands.

```
$ git config credential.helper store
$ git push http://example.com/repo.git
Username: YOUR_USERNAME
Password: YOUR_PASSWORD
```